# selecting complex data from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I have mysql table acc_records with columns 
`id(pk),acc_no,acc_name,date_created` .
I have to display the data acc_no,acc_name from that tableif two or more `ids(pks)` contains same `acc_no` or if two or more `ids(pks)` contains same `acc_name` and `date_created` and in the results exclude the latest result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please be more precise on how you want the data? Do you want the IDs or do you want the acc_name and date_created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to get the account names, dates, and the last id you would want through a subquery and join your original table to the sub table. The same needs to be done for the account numbers and the distinct ids need to be fetched (there might be some records which are in both the subtables).

In essence this is the query you would need.

```
select * from account_records ar inner join 

(
select distinct id from 
(
select ar.id as id from 
account_records ar inner join
(
  select count(*), max(id) as lastId, acc_name, date_created from account_records ar
  group by acc_name, date_created 
  having count(*) > 2
) aggr
on ar.acc_name = aggr.acc_name 
and ar.date_created = aggr.date_created
and ar.id < aggr.lastId 

union

select id from account_records ar inner join 
  (
    select count(*), max(id) as lastId, acc_no from account_records ar
    group by acc_no
    having count(*) > 2
   ) aggrId
on aggrId.acc_no = ar.acc_no
and ar.id < aggrId.lastId
  ) allIds
  ) distinctIds
on ar.id = distinctIds.id
;
```

Here's the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4a5d5/3).

Comment: You have missed one more condition that if two or more ids have same acc_no those records should also displayed excluding the latest record

Comment: oh k. but why would one account number be present twice? This is a record of account creation right? An account is usually created once right?

Comment: sorry I can't reveal all the things but according to that only we separate good accounts , bad accounts ,...etc.,thank you.

Comment: i'm not sure about how optimal this query is though. be careful when using it. I would rather merge the two result sets in code.